# How is Post's tautology theorem used in this proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

Could someone please explain to me how does the proof of I.4.3 reference I.4.1?

In I.4.3, you are given hypotheses about A and B being theorems. However, I.4.1 talks about tautologies (as inputs) not theorems.

How can someone use $\Gamma \vdash A$ + something about tautologies to yield $\Gamma \vdash B \implies A$?

See :Tourlakis (2003), *Lectures in logic and set theory*.
[image: Proof from Tourlakis 2003]

Comment: If we have $\Gamma\vdash A,$ then we have $\Gamma\models A.$ This is soundness, and was presumably proven before the more difficult completeness result.

Comment: Soundness has yet to be proven, it's on I.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to use [**I.3.7 Definition (Tautologically Implies)**, page 31](https://books.google.it/books?id=AHvoluqx7uoC&pg=PA31) :

> Let $\mathcal A$ and $\Gamma$ be respectively any formula and any set of formulas.
>   The symbol $\Gamma \vDash_{\text{Taut}} \mathcal A$, pronounced “$\Gamma$ *tautologically implies* $\mathcal A$”, means that every truth assignment $v$ that satisfies $\Gamma$ also satisfies $\mathcal A$.

We have $\mathcal A \vDash_{\text{Taut}} \mathcal B \to \mathcal A$ as well as $\mathcal B \vDash_{\text{Taut}} \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$.

We have to use them in the proof of :

> [**I.4.3 Metatheorem**. Any two theorems $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are provably equivalent (page 42)](https://books.google.it/books?id=AHvoluqx7uoC&pg=PA42).

Assume $\Gamma \vdash \mathcal A$.

Using **I.4.1 Metatheorem (Post’s “Extended” Tautology Theorem)**, we have $\mathcal A \vdash \mathcal B \to \mathcal A$.

Thus, by properties of $\vdash$, we get : $\Gamma \vdash \mathcal B \to \mathcal A$.

In the same way, from $\Gamma \vdash \mathcal B$ we have : $\Gamma \vdash \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$.

Finally, using : $\mathcal A \to \mathcal B,  \mathcal B \to \mathcal A \vDash_{\text{Taut}} \mathcal A \leftrightarrow \mathcal B$, we conclude with :

> > $\Gamma \vdash \mathcal A \leftrightarrow \mathcal B$.

Comment: Thanks very much Mauro, you're always very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

In Hilbert style proof systems, it is usually an axiom that the schema $\phi\to(\psi\to \phi)$ is tautological.   Additionally, Modus Ponens is a fundamental rule of inference (typically the only fundamental rule).

So since $A\to(B\to A)$ is a tautology, and using Modus Ponens, therefore if can you derive $A$, then you may infer that $B\to A$ is derivable in the same context.$$\begin{split}\Gamma &\vdash A&&\textsf{derived somehow}\\&\vdash A\to(B\to A)&\qquad&\textsf{via axiom P2}\\\hline\Gamma &\vdash B\to A&&\textsf{via modus ponens} \end{split}$$